# JavaFx text fonts are tiny on Windows 7

Tags: fonts, javafx, windows-7-x64

**UPDATE:**
I removed specifying font sizes and now the font size is readable - however, this means one cannot specify any font size at all - which is equally bad!

I developed my program on Windows XP. The font was set to 12 point for most fields. The size was readable and adequate. When I tried running on Windows 7, the font size on screen is tiny. A 12 size font now appears like it is size 6!
However, this is not uniform. Text that is set on some widgets - like on Table column headers and Choice boxes, appear large - 12 point size font like before. But now on the scaled down gui widgets, they are cut off.
The display resolution is defaulted to 1920 x 1080.
Here is a screenshot below.
For instance, here is the stock JavaFX tutorial sample for table running on Windows 7. It was modified to specify the font size. **Notice how tiny the font size 12 is on Win7.** Also see that the table column header font is much larger and overflows:

[image: screenshot of bug in JavaFX]

The code for the fxml file is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.*?> 
<?import javafx.collections.*?> 
<?import fxmltableview.*?> 
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<Scene xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" >
    <GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
        <padding>
            <Insets top="10" right="10" bottom="10" left="10"/>
        </padding>
        <Label  text="Address Book: This text is in font size 12 on Win7" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0">
            <font>
                <Font size="12.0"/>
            </font>
        </Label>
        <TableView GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
            <columns>
                <TableColumn text="First Name">
                    <cellValueFactory>
                        <PropertyValueFactory property="firstName" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn text="Last Name">
                    <cellValueFactory>
                        <PropertyValueFactory property="lastName" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
                <TableColumn text="Email Address">
                    <cellValueFactory>
                        <PropertyValueFactory property="email" />
                    </cellValueFactory>
                </TableColumn>
            </columns> 
                              <items>
                <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
                    <Person firstName="Jacob" lastName="Smith"  
                email="jacob.smith@example.com"/>
                    <Person firstName="Isabella" lastName="Johnson" 
                email="isabella.johnson@example.com"/>
                    <Person firstName="Ethan" lastName="Williams" 
                email="ethan.williams@example.com"/>
                    <Person firstName="Emma" lastName="Jones"
                email="emma.jones@example.com"/>
                    <Person firstName="Michael" lastName="Brown" 
                email="michael.brown@example.com"/>
                </FXCollections>
            </items> 
        </TableView>
    </GridPane>
</Scene>
```

Comment: I am not sure, but perhaps your issue is related to the interaction of [Windows DPI scaling and JavaFX](http://news.kynosarges.org/2013/08/09/javafx-dpi-scaling/).

Comment: @jewelsea as a workaround, how to reduce the font size of the table column headers and the choice boxes? Currently they overflow their bounds.

Comment: @jiujitsu, I don't know and I don't have the hardware and software setup to replicate this, so unfortunately I can't provide more assistance.

Comment: You may want to create a [program that replicates the issue](http://sscce.org/) and [log a bug report](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com) with your program, detailed environment description, reproduction steps and a link to a screenshot illustrating the issue.

Comment: You may wish to try [Java 8](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html) and review the instructions in the comment at the top of the the default [Java 8 modena.css stylesheet](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/tip/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) for "Resizing for different screen DPI".

Comment: @jewelsea Java 8 is not an option for me to use for my project until JavaFX 8 is officially released. I created a ticket here https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-32634